# Filter only folder info like name, id etc of google drive using Google API V3

Tags: asp.net, google-api, google-drive-api, postman, google-api-client

I want to filter only folder info like name, id etc of google drive using Google API V3 but still it gives information of other things like pdf etc. I am looking for folder info only.

I tried: 
    https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true&corpora=allDrives&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&pageSize=1000&mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.folder

And Getting (I am getting so many things and its just subset of that, last element u can see is a pdf info which should not come, I just want folder list):

```
{
    "kind": "drive#fileList",
    "nextPageToken": "SnS3QhUEpgrO3k595Zpei78DsYX6Nu7MbOruavva2vHZyCAAiyxmAmyCvXmvJDZf3GqpfryKG8TiUg==",
    "incompleteSearch": false,
    "files": [
        {
            "kind": "drive#file",
            "id": "1rbWEr5c96qiAV0oFGJhbcsXuCIzN08Pq",
            "name": "Test folder",
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
        },
        {
            "kind": "drive#file",
            "id": "1_OUGARZznIekMIvJdUY92B6mcMcrev6L",
            "name": "t",
            "mimeType": "*/*"
        },
        {
            "kind": "drive#file",
            "id": "1fUowckXE_rjmM9n_BvJy3woTY1FGX3Ao",
            "name": "t",
            "mimeType": "*/*"
        },
        {
            "kind": "drive#file",
            "id": "13eozlJ55JZ19_5BE0CJ_vUudVR9y-7o_",
            "name": "t",
            "mimeType": "*/*"
        },
        {
            "kind": "drive#file",
            "id": "1fuPoW-q0QOHvIQmpf3Gbs4qzmBd6M89H",
            "name": "Pro_React_16.pdf",
            "mimeType": "application/pdf"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### mimeType is not a parameter that can be specified directly for the method `Files: list`

Instead it must be specified within the query parameter `q`, as featured [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files).

**How to adapt your request?**

Change

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true&corpora=allDrives&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&pageSize=1000&mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.folder`

to

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true&corpora=allDrives&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&pageSize=1000&q=mimeType%20%3D%20'application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder'`

> Indeed, it is very helpful to use the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22corpora%22%3A%22allDrives%22%2C%22includeItemsFromAllDrives%22%3Atrue%2C%22pageSize%22%3A1000%2C%22q%22%3A%22mimeType%20%3D%20%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%27%22%2C%22supportsAllDrives%22%3Atrue%7D), especially if
>   after retrieving a response with the specified parameters you expand
>   the window and have a look at the resulting cURL syntax.